# How to get drive letter of Photoshop's active file

Tags: photoshop-script

In Photoshop 2020, I'm scripting and trying to isolate the drive letter of the active document from app.activeDocument.path.

My issue is, how do I do that? I'm getting some strange error messages, and Google searches aren't helping resolve the issue. I try to use the following functions:

- string()
- substring()
- substr()
- Mid()
- split()

Here's my code:

```
var teststring = app.activeDocument.path;
var t = teststring.toLowerCase();
```

But for every function I try, Photoshop gives me this error message:

`Error 24: teststring.[function name] is not a function.`

I've even tried functions that wouldn't make sense, such as toLowerCase() and toUpperCase(), just to see if I can use *any* string function in Photoshop.

Photoshop is telling me that all the string functions I've tried don't exist. is there a specific set of string functions for Photoshop scripting. I haven't found it anywhere. What string function can I use to get the drive letter from activeDocument.path? Or does Photoshop not have any string functions available?

Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

That's because Photoshop's path is an object.

```
var teststring = app.activeDocument.path;
alert(typeof(teststring)); // Object

// Turn the path into a string with either
var t = "" + teststring.toLowerCase();

var t = teststring.toString().toLowerCase();
alert(t); // /c/myfolder/myfile.psd
```

You should be able to use regex to get the drive letter from there:

```
// Replace all front slashes with back slashes (I use Windows)
t = t.replace(/\//g, "\\");

// Check if first two characters are a backslash and a non-backslash character
if (t.charAt(0) === "\\" && t.charAt(1) !== "\\")
{
  t = t.replace(/\\[a-zA-Z]\\/, t.charAt(1).toUpperCase() + ":\\");
}
var driveLetter = t[0];
alert(driveLetter); //c
```